# Using OS X JavaScript for Automation (JXA) to listen to "open location" Apple Event

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, javascript-automation

I am using OS X JavaScript for Automation (JXA), and I want to be able to capture the "open location" Apple Event.

Per http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/ , I have setup a customer URL handler.  How do I do the equivalent of

```
on open location this_URL
  ...
end open location
```

with JXA?  I tried all of the following, but could not get any of them to execute:

```
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

function run() {
   app.displayDialog(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}

function openLocation() {
   app.displayDialog(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}

function openDocuments() {
   app.displayDialog(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}

function onOpenLocation() {
   app.displayDialog(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}
```

Apple's JXA docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW15 ) don't discuss how to handle the open location event.  My script would get opened because I could get an alert to display if I added it outside the functions.  I just couldn't get a function to execute and be passed in the URL.

I am working around this by having a AppleScript handler that that then invokes my JXA code, but this is certainly less than ideal.

I also didn't see anything in the JXA Cookbook (https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook ) about this.

Comment: Great question.  I look forward to the answer.

Comment: Is the omission of an argument in your function signature a copy paste error? Because it should be `function openLocation(thisURL) { // process thisURL }` if it is meant to work…

Comment: @kopischke: no, I intentionally omitted the URL parameter (e.g., thisURL).  I am using the special "arguments" available to a JS function to determine whether my function was invoked.  I believe I tried this with an explicit parameter as you suggested, but should it matter?

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but to any present or future visitors from Google, the correct function name to use is `GURLGURL` (no, I'm not joking). Your function signature should look something like this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

function GURLGURL(url) {
  const App = Application.currentApplication();
  App.includeStandardAdditions = true;
  
  App.doShellScript(`echo ${url} > ~/Downloads/url-arg.txt`);
  return true;
}
```

I discovered this after reading through [this archived developer document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-SW17), and then probing my JXA script's `applet` process with the Console app. The message that gets dispatched is `GURLGURL` as in *get URL*.

Cheers to Apple for curating the worst developer experience for the best version of AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, the trick (for the moment) seems to be to pass control immediately to a second (JavaScript for Automation) script in the same bundle.

```
on open location strURL
    run script (path to resource "jsHandler.scpt" in directory "Scripts") with parameters {{|URL|:strURL}}
end open location
```

Comment: How do I access the parameters in the jsHandler.scpt? I've tried iterating over args from function run(args), but no joy.